# Subbasis for a topology two problems

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Problem 1: $\S$ $=$ $\{$ $(-\infty,a)$ $:$ $a\in \mathbb{R}$ $\}$ $\cup$ $\{$ $(a,\infty)$ $:$ $a\in \mathbb{R}$ $\}$ is a subbasis for $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.

Attempt: 
Clearly, $\S$ covers $\mathbb{R}$. I must show that $\tau$ (the topology generated by a subbasis) is the standard metric topology. Indeed, since every open interval can be expressed as the intersection of members in $\S$, and each open set with respect to the standard metric topology is the union of open sets, the result follows.

Problem 2: Given $\S$ in the previous example. Show that $\S_n=\{\pi_i^{-1}(S): S\in \S, i=1,2,..n $ $\}$ is a subbasis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My attempt:
To see this, wlog assume $n=2$. I must show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ =$\bigcup_{S\in \S_2}$ $\bigcup_{i=1}^2 \pi_i^{-1}(S)$ . Let $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$. By the previous example, $x\in S_1$ and $y\in S_2$ for some $S_1,S_2\in \S$. Hence, $(x,y)\in \pi_1^{-1}(S_1)\cup \pi_2^{-1}(S_2)$. Therefore, $(x,y)\in \bigcup_{S\in \S_2}\bigcup_{i=1}^2\pi_i^{-1}(S)$. Now I must show that the standard metric topology is the same as the topology generated by the subbasis.  To do this, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{B} =$ $\{$ $\bigcap_{i=1}^nS_i$ $:$ $S_i\in \S_2$ $,$ $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\}$ is a basis for the standard metric topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. In which case, the result will follow, since the topology generated by a basis is unique. By continuity of projection maps, each member of $\S_2$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since every member of $\mathbb{B}$ is the finite intersection of open maps, it follows that $\mathbb{B}$ is a subset of the standard topology. Since projections are open maps, if $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$  then $\pi_i(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $\pi_i(U)$ is the union of finite intersection of some sub collection of $\S$.  Hence the result follows.

Are my attempts correct?

Comment: Are you sure you typed the set § correctly? As is, you are taking the union of twice the same set.

Comment: @celtschk you're right. My apologies. I fixed it now.

Comment: What exaclty do you mean by "every open interval can be expressed as a members of §"?

Comment: In problem 2, what are the $\pi_i$?

Comment: @celtschk projection maps. My apologies, I thought that was standard notation

Comment: @G.Chiusole $(a,b)=(a,\infty)\cap (-\infty,b)$ assuming $a<b$.

Comment: Then I would write it as such. As it stands, one could think you are saying that every interval is in §

Comment: @G.Chiusole Thank you for the feedback. It was much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For problem 1 you only showed that all open sets of the standard topology are also open sets generated by §. To show that they are the same you also have to show that sets that are *not* open in the standard topology are also not open in the topology of §, or equivalently that all open sets generated by § are also open in the standard topology.

For problem 2, the things you detailed are all correct, as far as I can see, but the final “Hence the result follows” I cannot see. You definitely need to detail out why you think the result follows.

Comment: $\pi^{-1}(\bigcup_i\bigcap_j S_{ij})=\bigcup_i\bigcap_j\pi^{-1}(S_{ij})$

Comment: @topologicalorientablesurface: What is $S_{ij}$?

Comment: any collection of sets, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @topologicalorientablesurface: And in which way is that equation relevant to the “the result follows” part?

Comment: If $\pi_i(U)$ is the union of a finite intersection of members in $\S$ then the above equality holds.

Comment: I don't see an inequality anywhere. I'm not sure what you are talking about. Please be **explicit.**

Comment: I meant equality. My apologies if i'm not clear. I'm really trying to be.

Comment: @topologicalorientablesurface: You are aware that in general $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))\ne U$?